# Random Forest Algorithm Where to start?

Tags: classification, random-forest, real-time

I need to solve a real time classification problem using random forest algorithm.Can anyone suggest any book,website where I should start looking it ?

Comment: here under random-forest tag:) at least to further specify the question as to why your problem is so peculiar that the general RF references are not helpful.

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) and [Breiman's original article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324)? We will happily try to help you with more specific points that remain unclear to you. Please consider editing your question to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for the unspecific nature of question.This is my first one and I am just starting over a project which requires me to classify  a realtime data using random forests of which I have no idea.I have started reading wiki and the breiman article(thanks for that).Will try to be more specific from now.

Answer (score 1):

The RF algorithm is quite fast once built, so for most cases you won't have any trouble running data through your model in real time.  Just:

1. Build your model with data at hand, adjusting parameters to get a good predictive model.
2. Then have a look at the feature importances to see if you can trim down the set of variables you need for a good model.
3. Once you've gotten the minimum set of features and the best model, set up a system to generate those features from your real time data as it comes in.
4. Pump the generated features into your model and return the result.

If you are looking for an online version of RF, where the model itself gets updated as new data comes in, that is a different technique.  You can start with [Online Random Forests](http://lrs.icg.tugraz.at/pubs/saffari_olcv_09.pdf) and [Streaming Random Forests](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/ideas07.pdf) if you are going that route.